# Unable to Build App on iOS Simulator, but Android Works Fine - Xcode Error

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode, dart, xcodebuild

I am facing an issue while trying to run my Flutter app on an iOS simulator using Xcode. The app runs smoothly on Android devices, but when I attempt to launch it on an iPhone 14 simulator in debug mode, I encounter the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            1.7s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2023-08-05 01:00:25.408 xcodebuild[11793:9648559] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default
    (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
    xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
                { id:A628B341-6F32-408D-6FB6-D1B6607D2426 }

        Available destinations for the "Runner" scheme:
                { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:00008103-000A56263CD3001E }
                { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }

Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/pn/41kpr78131x00zrg7zqwrsmr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.UeSLMM/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirABaxrN/temporary_xcresult_bundle


Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
```

I'm puzzled as to why the app fails to build on the iOS simulator while it works flawlessly on Android. I've made sure to use the latest Flutter and Xcode versions, but the error persists. Could someone shed some light on what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, you can revert your Xcode version to an earlier release. On June 1, 2023, Apple introduced Xcode 14.3.1, which inexplicably prevented me from running simulators in VScode. To overcome this, I opted to download a previous iteration, namely Xcode 14.2. Subsequently, I made the necessary adjustment to my Xcode settings by selecting this downloaded version. To perform this adjustment, follow these steps: Navigate to Xcode > Settings > Locations, proceed to the Command Line Tools section, click on the dropdown menu, and then choose the version you downloaded.

For accessing and acquiring previous versions, you can visit the following website: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

I trust this information proves valuable. Having devoted a week to exploring multiple solutions, I found this approach to be the singular one that yielded positive results.

Answer (score 0):

Could you define if your project supports iOS 14,and perhaps try below scripts:

```
flutter clean
pod cache clean  --all
rm -rf ios/Flutter/Flutter.framework

flutter pub get
pod install
flutter run
```

PS: attach flutter doctor logs

Comment: Im not sure if the project is compatible with IOS 14, but when I run pod install, I get the following error:

[!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.

Flutter doctor logs:


[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.6, on macOS 13.4.1 22F770820d darwin-arm64, locale en-US)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 14.3.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.75.1)
[✓] Connected device (3 available)
[✓] Network resources

• No issues found!

Comment: I ran the pod install command in /ios, and got no errors, but the app is still not running on the IOS simulator. Flutter doctor logs are above.